# Logical operators in Apex

Tags: expressions

How do I combine OR's and AND? The below gives me an error.
Any pointers are helpful.

Thanks

---

```
// check changed values
if ((old.value = '2' || old.value = '3') && 
    (new.value = '0' || new.value = '1'))
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is because you're using the assignment (single equal) operator. Use double equals to check if values are equal.

Comment: And probably also because `new` cannot be used as a variable name, but it could just be a redaction.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The assignment was incorrect as mentioned by POZ. Now corrected and all works. My code writing skills are awful :-(.